# Flutter Annoying Black Stripe at the bottom of screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have made a Login Screen, the problem is I am getting a black stripe at the end of my screen, while in my code I have'nt added any color at the end, moreover I thought that this might because of sizebox, but even if I remove it, nothing really happens. Moreover at first when I was creating and debugging this code, there was no such line and once everything is done, it started appearing at the bottom..
Here's the output picture:
[image: Output Image]

Here's my UI code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topCenter, colors: [
          Colors.black,
          Colors.black87,
          Color(0xff0a0b0d),
        ])),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30,fontFamily: 'Signatra'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Welcome to T Post",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30, fontFamily: 'Signatra'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  )),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(220, 90, 30, 10),
                              blurRadius: 20,
                              offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            )
                          ]),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                    bottom: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade200))),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Phone Number",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                    bottom: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade200))),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Password",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Forget Password",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        color: Color(0xff0a0b0d),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Login",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 60,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Continue with social media",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Twitter",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Skype",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
      
    );
  }
```

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have containers wrapping their content, so it appears like a stripe.  Try having one of the containers filling the screen instead of wrapping the content.  What happens when you make the following change to the `SingleChildScrollView`?

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
    width: double.infinity,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,  // <<<<<< Add this line.
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topCenter, colors: [
      Colors.black,
      Colors.black87,
      Color(0xff0a0b0d),
    ]))
```